# List all Twig templates used in the current request

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony2 with Twig templating engine.

Is there any way to output a list of all Twig templates files loaded in the current request, including the ones loaded through `extends`, `include`, etc.?

That would make my life much easier when overriding third-party bundles' blocks, but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: [This bundle may come in handy for those who find this SO question in the future](https://github.com/Elao/WebProfilerExtraBundle)

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for such a tool for a long time but never found it... The debug options of twig are very limited, and there is no tool in the sf2 dev bar dedicated to it...

I always add twig or html comments on top of each of my templates to get an idea of where I am and why during development or on the final page.

Comment: Good idea of putting html comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this code](https://gist.github.com/Invis1ble/0b7afb8fed8f7ca70f3c), it puts filenames in HTML like this:

```
<!-- START templatename.html.twig -->
...
<!-- END templatename.html.twig -->
```

I know, that it is not a good solution, but it is better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

not a problem when you are working in dev in app_dev.php

expand bottom SF toolbar, click on 200 status or on @your_rote_name
you will redirect to smt like `localhost/_profiler/s0meha5h?panel=*`
then click on left menu on **TWIG** then url will be like `localhost/_profiler/s0meha5h?panel=twig`

and you will see all templates like FolderYourBundle:Folder:twig_file_name.html.twig that loads one by one!