# Symfony2 - How to determine which twig templates are rendered

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm looking for an easy easy way to determine which templates are being rendered on a page. Since it doesn't look like this information is currently being logged anywhere I'm thinking I'd have to modify some part(s) of the pipeline but I'm not sure what would be the most effective way of doing it.

Comment: A little searching [yielded this extra bundle for the Web Profiler](https://github.com/Elao/WebProfilerExtraBundle) - however I don't think it lists the current templates for a page.

Comment: This also looks to be a possible duplicate of [List all Twig templates used in the current request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109475/list-all-twig-templates-used-in-the-current-request)

Comment: @sjagr that seems to do what I need. good find! I'd recommend adding this to the other answer. Strangely enough, while I did search on SO before asking the question, the duplicate one you found did not come up.

Comment: Added it in as a comment per your recommendations. I varied my wording when I did my own research which landed me on the other question :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK symfony does not has something like this out of box.A possible  solution is to add html comments in your twig files that state the file rendered. like that you can know which files buy looking to page source.

Comment: Did you just copy your deleted answer from the other question? It looks like there are a couple of alternatives..

Comment: Nop I did not copy my answer. In fact I deleted My answer because it did not quite answer the question. I wrote an answer here so that people could find a solution without reading comments.